# how to upload image in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

Here is my settings.py:

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Here is urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('laxmi.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, documents_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Here is my model:

```
class Services(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    desc = models.TextField()
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='img')
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Views:

```
def index(request):
    why_choose_uss = why_choose_us.objects.all()
    servicess = Services.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'laxmi/index.html', {'servicess': servicess, 'why_choose_uss': 
    why_choose_uss})
```

Template:

```
{% for services in servicess %}
  <div class="col mb-4">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="{{services.img.url}}"class="card-img-top" alt="...">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{services.title}}</h5>
        <p class="card-text">{{services.desc}}</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Lern More</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

And here is an image upload from admin pannel but its not shwoing in template
[image]

[here it is model in admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5con.png)
[output in template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMQCe.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to substitute

```
<img src="{{services.img.url}}"class="card-img-top" alt="...">
```

with

```
<img src="{{services.img.url}}" class="card-img-top" alt="..." />
```

Comment: its not working i am getting all object of services in templates excepting images. i think i am making some mistake in url but where i dont know.

Comment: make a try to substitute "{{services.img.url}}" with "{{ request.get_host }}{{services.img.url}}"

Comment: Otherwise try to add "/" before the ">" closing part of tag "img".

Comment: put {{services.img.url}} directly in the template as html text and see what is the url coming out of it. does it show your image if you paste it in your browser url bar?

Comment: I edited my answer, refresh the page and try again with that substitution. It has to be the /> part

Comment: i put  directly in the template but not shown image

Comment: Could it be that "img" is a default variable that overwrite the one from your model? I would suggest you to rename img field of your model into something like "photo" or "picture", makemigrations, migrate, and then check again.